# What type of permission user needs in order to approve workflow task?

Tags: workflow, tasks

Is read only permission enough for user to approve a task in workflow? or I need to grant the user contribute rights in order to approve or reject a worfklow task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Any users that need to be approving or reject must have contribute (aka edit) rights on the workflow task list.

Thanks

Comment: Great. I added the user to a SP Group with Contribute and now the users can see and edit the task. Thanks Monica.

Comment: a quick question if ok :) does a user need to have any rights on the workflow tasks list if they do not approve it apart from making a request??